# Relationship between Laplacian and Hessian on compact Lie groups

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and compactly supported, one has
$$\int |\Delta f(\mathbf{x})|^2\,d\mathbf{x} = \int \| Hf(\mathbf{x}) \|_F^2\,d\mathbf{x}\,,$$
where $\Delta$ denotes the Laplacian, $H$ denotes the Hessian (matrix of second derivatives), and $\| \cdot\|_F^2$ denotes the Frobenius norm squared (the sum of squares of matrix entries). What can be said about compact Lie groups?

Specifically, I have two questions about this phenomenon:

*Nomenclature*: In this case where all norms are $L^2$, does this equality have a generally accepted name? What about the case when other norms are introduced?

*Lie groups*: I would like to understand in what sense this generalizes to compact Lie groups. What can be said about smooth $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: @Steven Gubkin It is discussed briefly in [arxiv:0704.2833](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2833) (see the 2nd page). To see it in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can cancel the terms of the form $(\partial^2 f/\partial x_i^2)^2$ from both sides and then judiciously apply integration by parts to each of the remaining terms: this results in a portion that cancels (as $f$ is compactly supported) and the integral of the product of a first and third derivative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Lie groups, I believe. Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. The Bochner formula on $1$-forms states that
$$\nabla^* \nabla \omega = (d \delta + \delta d)\omega - \mathrm{Ric}\,\omega.$$
Hence we have for any compactly supported function $f$ (writing round brackets for the $L^2$ scalar product) 
$$\|Hf\|_{L^2}^2 = \|\nabla d f\|_{L^2}^2 = (\nabla^* \nabla d f, df) = ((d \delta + \delta d - \mathrm{Ric})d f, df ) = (d\delta d f, d f) - (\mathrm{Ric}\, df, df)$$
Using that on functions, $\Delta f = \delta d f$, this is equal to
$$(d \Delta f, df) - (\mathrm{Ric}\, df, df) = \|\Delta f\|_{L^2}^2 - (\mathrm{Ric}\, df, df)$$
This is a standard formula of Riemannian geometry.

Comment: I was not aware of this beautiful, generic expansion in terms of the Ricci tensor. So...this reduces my question to understanding the Ricci tensor over Lie groups!

Comment: I think the signs in front of the Ricci tensor are wrong in the second and third displayed equation; also an appearance of $f$ is missing in the third displayed equation.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig: Do you know whether these formulae extend to connections in Hermitian bundles (with, obviously, the Ricci tensor replaced by something appropriate)?

Comment: What exactly would you like a formula for in this context?